# Unavailable .p12 option

Tags: apple-push-notifications, p12

I'm trying to renew my APNS certificate, so I created a new one, (the one that read Sandbox & Production) downloaded and imported it to my keychain.

The issue is that when I go to export it, the .p12 option is unclickable! It is there, but I can't select it!

Any idea what’s wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all I had to copy the APNS certificate to the `login` Keychain!